# Pass data to ngx-bootstrap Ahead-Of-Time (AOT)

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to pass a data to a component through modal of `ngx-bootstrap`. The scenario is my view is dependent to the data that I'm passing (`*ngFor`) and I need it in lifecycle hook of `ngOnInit()` or in `constructor`. However, even though I'm using the `initialState` of `ModalOptions`, I cannot get the data that I pass.

Here's my code.

**Parent Component**

```
_modalConfiguration: ModalOptions = {
   animated: true,
   keyboard: true,
   backdrop: true,
   ignoreBackdropClick: false,
   initialState: typeList
};

this.modalService.show(TranslationFormComponent, _modalConfiguration);
```

Note: I'm calling another component to show it as a modal, the HTML code is **not** on the parent `HTML`.

**TranslationFormComponent**

```
private typeList;
constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef, private modalService: ModalService) {
  console.log(bsModalRef);
  this.typeList = bsModalRef.content.typeList;
}
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.bsModalRef);
  this.typeList = this.bsModalRef.content.typeList;
}
```

**TranslationForm.html**

```
<select class="col-lg-12 form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let item of typeList" value="{{item.id}}">
      {{item.text}}
   </option>
</select>
```

So as you can see, I am dependent to the data that I am passing, but when the component was initialise, the data has not passed to the BsModalRef, but when I tried to remove the data dependency of my view, I was able to fetch the data. So I'm thinking about the timing.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle hook? It returns a `SimpleChanges` object that should have the latest data. 

Not sure if it will work for this use case.

Edit: Added code quotes to lifecycle and object name.

Comment: Can you make typeList an observable, so that you can subscribe to i, so timing will not be an issue as subscription will be notified on any changes in data.

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc actually I am thinking this approach as a work around, I posted this question to avoid this because maybe I'm just missing something. But if I got no choice, I might use other library or implement this work around.

Comment: If you have direct parent to child relationship then the best way it to pass data using @Input, otherwise you can not gurantee order of execution so observables for the rescue!